# How to check the version of Visual Studio 2017 offline installer?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

The layout update takes a long time and bandwidth and I would like to check what update is currently in the layout. Is there a way to check the current version number before I start the layout update?

I created the layout using methods descibed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Updates are done using methods descibed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: Hi, how did you create the layout update? Please go to layout folder and open Catalog.json or ChannelManifest.json to view the 'buildVersion' to know the current version number.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like productDisplayVersion is what I need for this purpose. I created the layout using methods described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation, please add a answer with your results and that will also help other community members who have the same or similar issues, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment from Sara Liu, I got the version number I was looking for.

Open the catalog.json file in the install folder, say under, d:\vs\2017 where the layout was created or updated. Open channelmanifest.json and look for productDisplayVersion.